# MVC - DropDownList/PartialView issue - "Viewdata has the key int.. ..must be IUnumerable..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedRating' is of type
>   'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

This is the error I get when I'm trying to add a DropDownList via partial view. I tried to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) but I somehow failed to do so due to my low experience in coding.

This is how my code look for the moment:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Rating()
    {
        RateReviewVM model = new RateReviewVM()
        {
            ReviewId = id,
            RatingList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
        };
        return View(model);
    }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Rating(RateReviewVM model) {

         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {                
            model.RatingList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
            return View(model);
         }

       //...
```

**View for _RatingPartial**

```
@model xxxx.ViewModel.RateReviewVM

<h6>Rate the review</h6>

using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<div class="form-group">


    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRating)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRating, Model.RatingList, "-Please select-", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedRating)

</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Rate</button>
    }
}
```

**This is how I try to display _RatingPartial view**

```
@{
    var newRating = new xxxx.ViewModel.RateReviewVM { ReviewId = Model.Id };

    Html.RenderPartial("_RatingPartial", newRating);

}
```

**Model**

```
    public class RateReviewVM {

            public System.Guid Id { get; set; }

            public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }

            public System.Guid ReviewId { get; set; }

            public bool HasLiked { get; set; }

            public Nullable<int> Rating { get; set; }

            public int SelectedRating { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RatingList { get; set; }
     }
```

**EDIT: ---**

**Details View(Main)**

```
    @model xxxx.Review

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    }

    @*@{
        //var newRating = new xxxx.ViewModel.RateReviewVM { ReviewId = Model.Id };

        @Html.RenderPartial("_RatingPartial", newRating)

    }*@

    <h2>Details</h2>

    <div>

        <h4>Review</h4>
        <hr/>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
            </dd>
            @* and so on..  *@

        </dl>
    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
```

**Controller for Details**

```
            public ActionResult Details(Guid? id) {

            Review review = db.Reviews.Find(id);

            return View(review);
        }
```

**Model Review for Details**

```
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }

        public System.Guid CreatorUserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        //etc - some irrelevant property        

        public virtual ICollection<RateReview> Users { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your `RenderPartial()` is just initializing a new instance of `RateReviewVM` and you have not populated the `RatingList` property of that instance (its `null`, hence the exception). Why are you using `RenderPartial()`? And what is the model in the main view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I thought that was the proper to display a partial. What should I use instead?

Comment: Your GET method suggests the model in the main view is already `RateReviewVM` so what is the point of `RenderPartial()`. Just move the code in the `_RatingPartial.cshtml` partial into the `Rating.cshtml` file and delete `RenderPartial()`

Comment: And if you did want to use a partial (but there is no point), then it would be `Html.RenderPartial("_RatingPartial", Model)` assuming the model in the main view is `RateReviewVM` and that view was generated by your `Rating()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke my main view uses the `Review` model, while `_RatingPartial` uses `RateReview`. That's why I can't have it directly into my main view.

Comment: Then show the relevant code in your question! (and if you want to generate the partial returned by the `Rating()` method, then its `@{ Html.RenderAction("Rating", new { reviewId = Model.Id }); }` assuming the method is `public ActionResult Rating(Guid ratingId)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh I was unclear about the main View. Main view is `Details`(see updated code), and it's using another model so called `Review`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the value of `RatingList` is `null` (refer [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a detailed explanation).

In you case, your using the `RenderPartial()` method to pass a model to the view, and you do not set the value of property `RatingList` (`RenderPartial` does not call your `public ActionResult Rating()` method.

You could solve the error by using

```
@{
    var newRating = new xxxx.ViewModel.RateReviewVM
    {
        ReviewId = Model.Id,
        RatingList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
    };
    Html.RenderPartial("_RatingPartial", newRating);
}
```

so that the property is populated, but since you already have a GET method, then it would be better to use the `RenderAction()` method which does call the server method

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Rating", yourControllerName, new { id = Model.Id }); }
```

Note I'm assuming your method is actually `public ActionResult Rating(Guid id)` since the current code would throw an exception since `id` is not declared.

However, that will not solve all your problems since the POST method returns the review is `ModelState` is invalid (as it should), but its a different view from your current one. It will also throw an exception because your not repopulating the `RatingList` property.

The correct approach to solve this is to have a view model for `Review` which contains another view model for comment.

```
public class ReviewVM
{
    ... properties of review including property for collection of existing commnets
    public CommentVM Comment { get; set; } // for generating a new comment form
}
```

and in the `Review.cshtml` view, add the form for generating new comment, and post back to to a method which has `ReviewVM` as the parameter. Then if `ModelState` is invalid, repopulate the properties of `ReviewVM` based on its ID, and repopulate the `RatingList` property of its `Comment` property. Alternatively, if your wanting to allow the user to add multiple comments for a Review, consider a dialog form for adding a new comment and use ajax to post the form.

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewBag for your dropdrownlist and it will work for partialView too. and then you don't need ViewModels. your model classes are fine to work with.

First add `CreateRate` action to `Reviews` Controller

```
 public ActionResult CreateRate(RateReview rate)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            rate.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.RateReviews.Add(rate);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Reviews", new { id = rate.ReviewId });
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Modify `Details` action to create a viewbag data as below

```
public ActionResult Details(Guid? id)
{

    Review review = db.Reviews.Find(id);
    ViewBag.RatingList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));

    return View(review);
}
```

Modify your PartialView as below to target `CreateRate` action, add a HiddenFor Helper for ReviewId and modify dropdownlistfor to read from ViewBag. I use RateReview Model instead of your ViewModel

```
@model WebApp.Models.RateReview


@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateRate", "Reviews")) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>RateReview</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReviewId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedRating, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRating, (ViewBag.RatingList as SelectList), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedRating, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

at end your `Details` View is just fine :

```
@model WebApp.Models.Review

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

@{
    var newRating = new WebApp.Models.RateReview { ReviewId = Model.Id };

    Html.RenderPartial("_RatingPartial", newRating);

}


<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
<h4>Review</h4>
<hr />
...
```